# cisco switch port mapping by ip or mac using python

Tags: networking, cisco, python

I am working on some networking related stuff. here is the code i created to find the server connected cisco switch in the Data center.  But we have multiple  cisco os type. like Cisco ios and NXOS.  login in to each device to get neighbor info or mac table is the better way to achieve this. Guys is thee any other way to get cisco switchport mapping from ip or mac ?

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import os
import json
import re



app_server_mgmt_ip = '192.168.10.20'
app_switch_mgmt_ip = '192.168.20.5'
username = ''
password = ''
ip = app_switch_mgmt_ip


from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_ios_xrv = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_xr',
    'ip':   app_switch_mgmt_ip,
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'port' : 22,          # optional, defaults to 22
    'secret': 'secret',     # optional, defaults to ''
    'verbose': False,       # optional, defaults to False
}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_ios_xrv)
output = net_connect.send_command('sh ver')
datai222 = str(output)
print datai222

output = net_connect.send_command('sh ip route '+app_server_mgmt_ip)
data = str(output)
displaymessage1 = data
#print displaymessage1

output2 = net_connect.send_command('sh ip arp '+app_server_mgmt_ip)
data2 = str(output2)
##print data2
stringsplit2 = data2.split()
#print stringsplit2
stringsplit2value = stringsplit2[11].strip()
displaymessage2 = data2
#print displaymessage2

#third command
output3 = net_connect.send_command('ping '+app_server_mgmt_ip)
data3 = str(output3)
displaymessage3 = data3
#print displaymessage3
import time
#time.sleep(1)
#print "4th command"
#print "stringsplit2value"+stringsplit2value
output4 = net_connect.send_command('sh mac address-table address '+stringsplit2value)
#output4 = net_connect.send_command('sh mac address-table address '+stringsplit2value)
data4 = str(output4)
displaymessage4 = data4
#print displaymessage4
stringsplit4 = data4.split('\n')
##print stringsplit4
stringfound4 = str(stringsplit4[7]).find('Po')
#print stringfound4
if(stringfound4  == -1):
        print("Not found")
else:
        stringsplit4split = stringsplit4[7].split('Po')
        stringsplit4splitvalue4 = stringsplit4split[1].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the right commands, but you might have some wrong assumptions.

The port on a switch where a server is connected can be found with *show mac address-table* but only if the switch recently learned about this mac address. The switch is learning the mac address if it needs to forward layer 2 traffic for this server.

The port found can be a port where the server is directly connected or it can be a port where another switch is connected if that switch is on the path to the server.

The IP address of the server will normally not be known by switches. When you ping the IP address of the server, you might be using the management network. As this is usually a different network, the ARP table will show the gateway MAC address for the server IP instead of the server MAC address.

To find the port where the server is connected the best option is to go on the device that acts as a gateway for that server. On that device, ping the server and check the ARP table for the MAC address.
Then, check the forwarding tabe to see the port used to forward traffic for that MAC.
The port will be either a downlink and you will have to check again on the switch connected there, or it will be the port you are looking for.